# Want to fetch the id of the different div elements on the click of p element using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a page with p tags and div element, the div element is set with display:none in the starting so, I just want to display the different divs as shown below inside the body tag on the click of the p tag but i got stuck in fetching the different id of the divs. Please do help me out from this situation.Below is my code. Thanks

```
 <script>
      function toggle(id)// here is the function which gets the different ids of the div
      {  var element = document.getElementById(id);
            for(i=1; i<3; i++)
        {
           if(element[i].style.display == "none") 
            {
               element[i].style.display = "block";
            }
            else
            {
                element[i].style.display = "none"
            }
        }

      }
      </script>
    <body>
      <p onclick="toggle('div1')">Sentence1</p>
      <p onclick="toggle('div2')">Sentence2</p>
      <div id="div1" name="Name 1" style="display:none; width:400px; height:300px; border:1px solid black; background-color:yellow;" id="div1">Barun Ghatak</div>
      <div id="div2" style="display:none; width:400px; height:300px; border:1px solid black; background-color:black;" id="div2">Bhoopi</div>
     </body>
```

Comment: Why are to specifying `id` 2 twice..? What's the purpose of the loop? please void using inline styles...

Answer (score 1):

You only have one of each div, so you don't need the loop. Just use

```
 function toggle(id)// here is the function which gets the different ids of the div
 {  
    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    if(element.style.display == "none") 
    {
       element.style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
       element.style.display = "none"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` returns a single object and not an array.

If you want to get both the `div`s, I suggest using a class to get them.

Comment: thanks sir i appreciate your valuable comments i will try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to only show one at a time, for example if you were building a tabs, then you could use this code to hide all the other divs first, then show only the one you want to toggle. Otherwise, if you're happy to toggle them, you can use the code posted by the others.

JS Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ecs77e9a/

**HTML**

```
<p onclick="toggle('div1');">Sentence1</p>
<p onclick="toggle('div2');">Sentence2</p>

<div id="content">
      <div id="div1" name="Name 1" style="display:none; width:400px; height:300px; border:1px solid black; background-color:yellow;" id="div1">Barun Ghatak</div>
      <div id="div2" style="display:none; width:400px; height:300px; border:1px solid black; background-color:black;" id="div2">Bhoopi</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function toggle(id)
{ 
    //Hide all other divs first
    var divs = document.getElementById('content').childNodes;
      for ( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
        if ( divs[i].nodeName == "DIV" ) {
             var div = document.getElementById(divs[i].id);
              div.style.display = "none";
        }
      }   

    //Show the one that's being requested
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.display = "block";

}
```